# How to use the same form for add and edit in laravel

Tags: laravel

I'm new to laravel,i want to use the same form for add and edit.I created an form and form insertion is ok but i need to use the same form edit based on the id selected.When click the  edit icon i want to direct the same page displaying the contents to edit.So give me idea for  implementing this.

```
<form method="POST" action="/categoryinsert">
              <input type = "hidden" name = "_token" value = "<?php echo csrf_token(); ?>">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <div class="form-group">

                    <div class="col-md-4">
                    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Category</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="category" id="category" placeholder="Enter Category">
                    </div>
                  </div>

                <div class="card-footer">
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                </div>
              </form>
```

Comment: Show the form you have created

Answer (score 0):

```
// To create a new user in controller
public function create()
{
    // user/createOrUpdate.blade.php view
    return View::make('user.createOrUpdate');
}

// To update an existing user
public function edit($id)
{
    $user = User::find($id);
    // user/createOrUpdate.blade.php view
    return View::make('user.createOrUpdate')->with('user', $user);
}
```

Add/edit in view with the help of user model

```
@if(isset($user))
    {{ Form::model($user, ['route' => ['updateroute', $user->id], 'method' => 'patch']) }}
@else
    {{ Form::open(['route' => 'createroute']) }}
@endif

    {{ Form::text('fieldname1', Input::old('fieldname1')) }}
    {{ Form::text('fieldname2', Input::old('fieldname2')) }}
    {{ Form::submit('Save', ['name' => 'submit']) }}
{{ Form::close() }}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// To create a new user in controller
public function create()
{
    // user/createOrUpdate.blade.php view
     return view('user.createOrUpdate')->with([

        'view_type' => 'create',
    ]);
}

// To update an existing user
public function edit($id)
{
    $user = User::find($id);
    // user/createOrUpdate.blade.php view
    return view('user.createOrUpdate')->with([
        'view_type' => 'edit',
         'user' => $user

    ]);
}




<form action="{{ ( $view_type == 'edit' ? route('example', $id) : route('control.mentors.store')) }}" role="form" method="post" name="frmDetail">
```